# Jquery appendTo a specific table ID not working

Tags: jquery

I have a table with one `<tr>` and 6 `<td>`'s inside. I am using a bit of code to remove the tr and then placing a new tr tag after the last td.

Before

```
<table id="datatable" class="datatable_class">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">title 1</td>
        <td id="td2">contents 1 need to go to new tr</td>
        <td id="td3">title 2</td>
        <td id="td4">contents 2 need to go to new tr</td>
        <td id="td5">title 3</td>
        <td id="td6">contents 3 need to go to new tr</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

After

```
<table id="datatable" class="datatable_class">
<tbody>
        <td id="td1">title 1</td>
        <td id="td2">contents 1 need to go to new tr</td>
        <td id="td3">title 2</td>
        <td id="td4">contents 2 need to go to new tr</td>
        <td id="td5">title 3</td>
        <td id="td6">contents 3 need to go to new tr</td>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

What I am trying to achieve now is to `.appendTo()` all the odd td's to my newly created tr. this works fine but problem now is that I have another table in my `<body>` and when I start moving td's around, I also move td's from my other table to this new tr.

I tried using this to filter with no luck

`$("#datatable > tbody > td.odd").appendTo('#fix_name').css( "background-color", "red" );`

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/d6668wLf/3/)

Comment: why a -1 on this question? sorry for trying to learn

Comment: The *after* HTML in not valid HTML; `td` elements always have to have a parent `tr` element. Not sure that you need all those `id`'s. ... Can you clearly outline what you want to achieve.

Comment: `.odd` is not a class in your HTML. you should use `:odd`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can move the desired table cells without affecting the second table. And to be more precise your can use the table ID instead of `table:first` - `#datatable td:odd` is a more precise selector.

```
$('#simple_button').click(function () { 
    $( '<tr id="fix_name"/>' ).insertAfter( $("#td6").closest('tr') );

    $( 'table:first td:odd' ).appendTo('#fix_name').css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6668wLf/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this isn't exactly what you're hoping for -- I'm a bit confused by why you're removing the TR.  But, if I understand what you're trying to do, I think you can fix your problem pretty easily by changing this:

```
$("#datatable > tbody > td.odd").appendTo('#fix_name').css( "background-color", "red" );
```

to this:

```
$( '#datatable td:odd' ).appendTo('#fix_name').css( "background-color", "red" );
```

(Changing the selector to ("#datatable td:odd")).  You can check out the results with this [edit of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6668wLf/4/), which I think does what you want.

Hopefully that works for you; otherwise, I'd recommend re-thinking the  removal.  Note that adding an `id` to the first row (or any other mechanism of selecting the first row, e.g., `$('#data-table tbody tr:nth-child(1)')`) would work just as well and maintain proper formatting.  You can check an example out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d6668wLf/6/).

Comment: thank you for helping out. I am very new to jquery and programming in general so it is nice to have people help out.  very frustrating to get down voted on my question. Cheers for the answers. Adding an id might be the right solution for working it out ;)